# Hi everyone, i am working with dynamixel AX-12A, upto which maximum angle i can move it?

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the [this dynamixel tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials). Is it possible to make it move 360 degree or upto which maximum angle it can be moved? Also how can i change the speed of dynamixel AX-12A?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228535/hi-everyone,-i-am-working-with-dynamixel-ax-12a,-upto-which-maximum-angle-i-can-move-it?/) by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi man, may be you should check [here](http://support.robotis.com/en/techsupport_eng.htm#product/dynamixel/mx_series/mx-64.htm), find the motor mode u r using, and then find its max-min paras respectively.

---

Originally posted by [Wine](https://answers.ros.org/users/22056/wine/) with karma: 43 on 2016-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0